# Converting string to double with dot

Tags: java, string, double, decimal

I need to convert string value to double with dot. Here is simple code

```
double dValue=Double.parseDouble("999999999.99");
System.out.println(dValue);
output is: 9.9999999999E8
```

When i gave value like 10000 or 100000 it works. Help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: `999999999.99` is equivalent to `9.9999999999E8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BigDecimal` and `toPlainString()` for that.

```
BigDecimal dValue= new BigDecimal("999999999.99");  
System.out.println(dValue.toPlainString());
```

**Output:**

```
999999999.99
```

Comment: Thank you islam. Also i need to divide this value by 2. How to achieve this. And the precision value should be round. Could you help me

Comment: @MuthuVikki see for division ``dValue.divide(new BigDecimal(2));``

Comment: @MuthuVikki for precision ``new BigDecimal("23.45435436").setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)``

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.format

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", dValue));
```